# learn SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Which is the best tutorial site or document for SSRS 2008 other than msdn site ?

Comment: if MSDN does not help you then look for Books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something more accessible than MSDN try

[Accelbrate SSRS Tutorial](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssrs_2008_tutorial.htm)

It's not very detailed, but it should work as a great primer if you're looking to jump right in.

Comment: Atleast we can get a starting.......

Comment: I already have this tutorial.......good for a starting.....thought whether anything better than this.....then go for MSDN !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this site ... it is pretty good with screenshots:

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/26/tutorials/4598/getting-started-with-ssrs-part-1-sql-server-reporting-services-overview-and-installing-in-windows-se.aspx